# Подскажите как правильно переписать часть кода с Jquery на JS по ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно переписать часть кода с Jquery на JS по ES6?

вот участок с которым возникла сложность. Буду рад совету по остальному коду если вдруг там что не так

```js
$("<span class=\"pip\">" +
    "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
    "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
    "</span>").insertAfter("#photos");

$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
});
```

Скрипт в песочнице

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/6tmj8h2y/1/)

дополнительно дублирую JS сюда

```js
if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    document.getElementById('photos').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        let photos = e.target.files,
            photosLength = photos.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < photosLength; i++) {
            let f = photos[i];
            let fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                let file = e.target;
                $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                    "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                    "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Remove image</span>" +
                    "</span>").insertAfter("#photos");
                $(".remove").click(function(){
                    $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                });
            });
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    });
} else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
}
```

Comment: и зачем?.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо [`insertAfter`](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) можно воспользоваться методом [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) указав в качестве первого параметра значение `afterend`.

Вместо склейки строк, можно воспользоваться [Шаблонными строками](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
`<span class="pip">
    <img class="imageThumb" src="${e.target.result}" title="${file.name"/>"
    <br/><span class="remove">Remove image</span>
</span>`
```

Вместо метода [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) можно использовать [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)

В итоге код может принять вид:

```
document.getElementById('photos').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',
    `<span class="pip">
        <img class="imageThumb" src="${e.target.result}" title="${file.name}"/>"
        <br/><span class="remove">Remove image</span>
    </span>`
);

// document.querySelectorAll(".remove") // в этой строке выбираются все элементы с классом `remove` на странице, даже те, которым уже добавлен обработчик.
//         .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(){
// чтобы не добавлять повторно, можно искать элемент `remove` только внутри только что добавленного элемента, который идет сразу после элемента `#photos`, 
// этот элемент можно получить с помощью метода, nextElementSibling
document.getElementById('photos')
    .nextElementSibling
    .querySelector('.remove')
    .addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.parentElement.remove();
    });
```

Метод [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) возвращает HTMLElement следующий непосредственно за текущим.

Comment: если согласны - добавьте к себе исправление, а я удалюсь

Comment: @Leonid, да, я думал об этом, но в данном случае - это не нужно, `.remove` лежит внутри `.pip`, поэтому можно не проверять.

Comment: Не совсем, если .remove несколько, а мы делаем перебор нескольких элементов, то удалить надо тех родителей, которые имеют определенный признак, а у вас все удаляются

Comment: @Leonid, удаляется родитель элемента по которому кликнули.

Comment: спасибо всем! Подскажите только почему то теперь код не срабатывает( превьюшки перестали выводиться https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/6tmj8h2y/3/

Comment: Да, но всякий, а нужен только тот, который имеет класс pip

Comment: @Vlad, потому что ты не те кавычки используешь, посмотри внимательнее какие нужны.

Comment: @Leonid. да, но в данном случае - это не существенно. Гораздо более существенней, что на уже присутствующие элементы remove добавляются обработчики

Comment: Хотя!!!!! Можно в этом случае изначально другую выборку сделать, только те элементы, родители которых .pip!!! То есть, document.querySelectorAll(". pip .remove"). Тогда все идентично.

Comment: @Leonid, скорее брать элемент который мы добавили и искать remove только внутри него

Comment: @Grundy с апострафами почему редактор ругается http://i.imgur.com/YWlsh3M.png

можно пожалуйста итоговый вариант как должно быть?

Comment: @Vlad, плохой редактора :) возьми другой ну и еще у меня опечатка :-) была не закрыта фигурная скобка.

Comment: @Grundy да нормальный, это я нуб) поправил опечатку http://i.imgur.com/ss9d6RS.png, но скрипт перестал работать( в чем может быть дело? https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/6tmj8h2y/5/

Comment: @Vlad, еще одна опечатка в функции `insertAdjacentHTML` не хватало `d`

Comment: @Grundy да сейчас все хорошо! Спасибо! шторм оказывается все подсвечивал буду учитывать на будущее!

Comment: @Grundy только теперь remove превьюшек не удаляется( https://jsfiddle.net/usdbuy/6tmj8h2y/6/

Comment: @Vlad, ага, код с выбором элемента улучшил, и теперь выбирается только один элемент, а forEach убрать забыл. Поправил

Answer (score 2):

Попробую так. Здесь parent.pip каждый второй. Событие для любого .remove. Удаление любого родителя, включая и тех, которые не имеют класс .pip

```
<div class="pip"><p class="remove">Some text</p></div>
<div><p class="remove">Some text</p></div>
<div class="pip"><p class="remove">Some text</p></div>
<div><p class="remove">Some text</p></div>
<div class="pip"><p class="remove">Some text</p></div>
<div><p class="remove">Some text</p></div>

document.querySelectorAll(".pip .remove").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(){
this.parentElement.remove();
    }));
```

По последнему подправлю. Parent() в jQuery позволяет сделать выборку по селектору, в данном случае по классу pip:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".remove").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(this.parentElement.classList.contains('pip')) this.parentElement.remove();
}));
```

Comment: спасибо! за отклик!